# How to find a value in all features of dataframe

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to impute the value in a dataframe.

Code :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
fill_nan = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', axis=1)
general_population_cleaned = pd.DataFrame(fill_nan.fit_transform(general_population), columns=general_population.keys())
general_population_cleaned.isna().any().values
```

But got error :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6B'
```

How do i find the value '6B' in entire dataframe (by searching through all columns) ?

Comment: Check the dtypes of all the columns, the column with '6B' will have object as its dtype, later you can search for the row in that column `df[df['object_column'] == '6B']`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me identify the Object type column - 
df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])